# How to connect Visual Studio 2022 Mac to create-react-app

Tags: create-react-app, visual-studio-mac-2022

I have never used Visual Studio for Mac before (not VS Code). I want to try out a tutorial to learn VS Studio by making a simple react app. I've tried creating a new project with VS studio, and then running npx create-react-app  in the folder of the new project, but VS studio doesn't see the new folder. I've also tried opening the folder created by create-react-app , but VS Studio refuses to recognize it as a volder it knows, it's greyed out. Thanks for helping out on this basic beginning step.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft's documentation on using React in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs-with-react-and-jsx?view=vs-2022) (see "Applies to" section at top of page) implies that using Visual Studio for Mac with React at the very least does not work with React the same way that Visual Studio (for Windows) does and may even suggest that some functionality is not be supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Visual Studio Project of template Web and Console -> React js and it will create a react app in the ClientApp folder of the project which you can work on. It will have a asp c# component in the project but that will be for in case you want to write server side which you can ignore for your development (if not needed). PS: I do not think we can create and run Node.js server side in visual studio ... atleast I am not aware how! being Microsoft i presume they will want you to write server side in ASP .NET

Comment: thank you. So if we want to use an existing project, is there any way to "attach" Visual Studio to it?